# Master and Child List Relationship

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

i have a small requirement where in i want to connect Parent List to 2 child list.
 
i am not sure how to achieve this. 
if there is any reference where through which i can achieve it , it would be great.
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to connect parent list and two child lists, by getting column value?

If you want to get the column value from another list, you can use Look Up column to get information from another list.

Comment: yes i have completed the requirement. i connected the list view by editing the webpart